# SQL Select one row for each category type

Tags: sql, db2

I've the data in my table in following format.

```
id | person_id| category | value| updated_date
-----------------------------
 1 | p1       |race  | r1 | 2015-02-26
 2 | p1       |race  | r2 | 2015-02-26
 3 | p2       |race  | r3 | 2015-02-27
 4 | p2       | race | r1 | 2015-02-28
 5 | p1       | lang | l1 | 2015-02-26
```

Now, I'm filtering based on the person's id. I need following in the result set.

1. I need a record for each category that exists for this person.
2. If there is more than one record for a category, list the once that is updated last.
3. If the updated dates are same, get the first one in the list.

For p1,

```
1 | p1       |race  | r1 | 2015-02-26
5 | p1       | lang | l1 | 2015-02-26
```

Comment: Define "first in the list".  SQL doesn't really have a concept of "order" as such, and relying on auto-gen ids (if that's what `id` is here) isn't something you should usually do.  Why are you switching from most-recently updated to earliest updated?  Or did you mean earliest updated anyways, and you just need higher resolution on `updated_date` (perhaps you should make it a timestamp)?  This looks like a classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, do the standard answers not work?

Answer (score 0):

It's something like this.  because id is not a group by field because it changes on every row you select the min(id) for the group by personid,category, value.

```
select min(id), personid, category, value, max(updated_date)
group by personid, category, value 
having Max(updated_date)     

/* min(id) is just to return the value of id 
for the row having max(update_date)  
having max(update_date) get's the highest date*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this with `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.personid = t.personid and
                        t2.category = t.cateogory and
                        (t2.updated_date > t.updated_date or
                         t2.updated_date = t.updated_date and t2.id < t.id
                        )
                 );
```